# Resuming 0 */3 * * * Crontab process affect hour upon which runs occur?

Tags: cron

I have a crontab set up to [execute the 0th minute of every 3rd hour every day](http://www.cronchecker.net/check?utf8=%E2%9C%93&statement=0%20*%2F3%20*%20*%20*%20perl%20test.pl%20&button=)

The crontab syntax for this is:

```
0 */3 * * * perl test.pl
```

Will this always run on the 0th minute of some specific hours of the day that are 3 hours apart. Or, will the time at which I install the new crontab affect the hour that this runs?

Comment: this will run on 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21 hours.

Comment: What about something like `0 */5 * * * perl test.pl` where the hours between is not a factor of 24?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cron will execute on Hours that are divisible by 3 so it should not matter at which time its started. The next occurance of an hour Divisible by 3 will be the first execution of your cron.

As per Chiyaan Suraj's comment, this will run on 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21 hours.

On your second comment, this will be on hours divisible by 5 (0,5,10,15,20)